# Why are JJ Electronic R.F. preamp tubes preferred over A.F. tubes in guitar amps?

Tags: amplifier, vacuum-tube, preamp

JJ Electronic has both R.F. (radio-frequency) and A.F. (audio frequency) versions of some of [their tubes](http://www.jj-electronic.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=15&Itemid=10). 
Yet in far the most tubeshops for guitar amps they only sell the R.F. versions ([ECC83 S - 12AX7](http://www.jj-electronic.com/pdf/ECC%2083%20S.pdf), [ECC803 S](http://www.jj-electronic.com/pdf/ECC%20803%20.pdf) etc.)

Why is the R.F. version preferred over the corresponding A.F. version?

(when speaking of power tubes, EL34, 6L6 etc the A.F. version seem to be preferred)

All spec sheets can be found [here](http://www.jj-electronic.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=15&Itemid=13), click the "more" links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see nothing in the [more extensive data sheet](http://www.mullardmagic.co.uk/ecc83-12ax7-cv4004-cv492-b339-m8137-6057-twin-triode-valve-various-manufacturers) for the ECC83S that makes it any more suitable for RF than AF. In fact on the link I've provided, Mullard say this: -

> The ECC83 high impedance amplifier triode was designed specifically
>   for audio use and has a high amplification factor of 100.

[image]

The ECC83C is two triodes in one package and here's another good use of it at audio frequencies, a balanced microphone preamplifier: -

[image]

Here's a circuit that uses the ECC83S as a differential amplifier feeding a push-pull stage: -

[image]

Neither Mullard nor most of the circuits hint that it is an RF only device.

I can only conclude that it is marketing hype or a mistake that lables the ECC83S as "RF". In fact if you follow the ECC803 (RF) link it takes you to a data sheets that shows this: -

[image]

Comment: Thanks Andy, I suspected that too. I just received a rather unclear answer from JJ - "markings A.F. and R.F. was used for indication primary purposes in the past." - which sort of indicates that there is no difference any more.

Comment: Also, on one device they typed "B.F." which of course means absolutely nothing - typos etc..

Answer (score 3):

The ECC83 is part of a common series of twin triodes, available with different values of mutual conductance (gm) and output impedance.

These were :

(Mullard)   (Brimar)   gm       Anode impedance
ECC81           12AT7          5.5mA/v  10 kilohms
ECC82           12AU7          3.1mA/v  7.7 kilohms
ECC83           12AX7          1.6mA/v  62.5 kilohms

These are referred to in the Brimar databook as "high slope", "low mu" and "high mu" respectively.

Despite the low mutual conductance, the ECC83 can offer highest gain into a high load impedance, which may make it more useful. What each valve will do (gain, noise, distortion) depends on the circuitry around it - bias voltages, cathode currents, output impedance.

As Andy says there's nothing really AF or RF specific to any of them, though Brimar mention that the "high slope" 12AT7 (labeled as "AF" in your source) makes a good "frequency changer" (i.e. mixer) up to 500 MHz' when biassed to be non-linear.